# JavaScript Help - Click Event Listener to activate 1 Element Node and deactivate the others

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck. I'm a beginner at JavaScript and here is what I am trying to do.

I'm adding a `"click"` eventListener to my `.tab-container`. When I click the `.tab` element, it will perform `event.target.matches(".tab")`.

If it does match, it's going to loop through the NodeList of the `.tab` elements and compare them to the `event.target`.

The element that equals `event.target` will have its className updated to make it active `class="tab active"`. Any other tab will have the className of `class="tab"` so that it is not active.

**JS**

```
var tabContainer = document.querySelector(".tab-container");
var tabElements = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
var viewElements = document.querySelectorAll(".view");

var tabContainer = document.querySelector(".tab-container");
var tabElements = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
var viewElements = document.querySelectorAll(".view");

tabContainer.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target.matches(".tab")) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tabElements.length; i++) {
            if (tabElements[i] === event.target) {
                event.target.className = "tab active";
            } else if (tabElements[i] !== event.target) {
                event.target.className = "tab";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tab-container">
    <div class="tab active" data-view="html">HTML</div>
    <div class="tab" data-view="css">CSS</div>
    <div class="tab" data-view="javascript">JavaScript</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your html?

Comment: You don't need `else if` to check the exact opposite, just use `else`. Anyway, do some basic debugging. `console.log()` stuff to check that it actually contains what you think it contains. Fumbling around in the dark, it's no wonder this is taking you half an hour.

Comment: Added to the post!

Comment: The problem is you're not exiting the loop, and if you click any tab other than the last one, the rest of the loop will remove the class again. What I would do instead: 1. remove the class from all tabs 2. add it to the clicked one. much shorter that way: https://jsfiddle.net/ycgz8x37/

Comment: Thank you @ChrisG - I was console logging the whole time I just wasn't sure why, what you explained in your first post, was happening. I wasn't getting returned any errors :/

The perks of being a newb, I guess..

Comment: Ah, ok, you should definitely mention that :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it should work:

```js
var tabContainer = document.querySelector(".tab-container");
var tabElements = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
var viewElements = document.querySelectorAll(".view");

tabContainer.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("tab")) {
    for (i of tabElements) {
      i.className = 'tab';
        if (i === event.target) {
          event.target.classList.add('active');
          console.log(i.innerHTML + ' is active');
        }
     }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tab-container">
        <div class="tab active" data-view="html">HTML</div>
        <div class="tab" data-view="css">CSS</div>
        <div class="tab" data-view="javascript">JavaScript</div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be setting event.target's className (especially in the else condition)

Try

```
var tabContainer = document.querySelector(".tab-container");
var tabElements = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
var viewElements = document.querySelectorAll(".view");

tabContainer.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target.matches(".tab")) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tabElements.length; i++) {
            if (tabElements[i] === event.target) {
                tabElements[i].className = "tab active";
            } else {
                tabElements[i].className = "tab";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Notice that its `tabElements[i]` instead of `event.target`. I've also removed the redundant if condition like Chris G mentioned.

Comment: Don I tested this out and it works. Thank you very much. You also still have the else statement in there, so I'm not sure what you mean? Can you clear that up for me?

Comment: i meant i removed the the if condition after the else statement `if (tabElements[i] !== event.target)` (fixed that mistake in the answer)